# Authenticate aws configure credentials inside Docker

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I wrote a python flask API that takes an image as an input, uploads it on an S3 bucket and then process it in a function. When I run it locally, it works just fine. But when I run it through Docker image, it gives `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

My python code:

```
import boto3

s3BucketName = "textract_bucket"
region_name = 'ap-southeast-1'

aws_access_key_id = 'advdsav',
aws_secret_access_key = 'sfvsdvsdvsdvvfbdf'

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key,
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')

# Amazon Textract client
textractmodule = boto3.client('textract', region_name = region_name)

def extract_text(doc_name):
    
    response = textractmodule.detect_document_text(
        Document={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': s3BucketName,
                'Name': doc_name,
            }
        })
    
    extracted_items = []
    for item in response["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
            extracted_items.append(item["Text"])
            
    return extracted_items
```

The flask API:

```
@app.route('/text_extract', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    
   if request.method == 'POST':
       
      img = request.files['file']
      file = secure_filename(img.filename)
      bucket.Object(file).put(Body=img)
      output = extract_text(file)
          
      return {'results': output}

app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt update 
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

The docker commands that I ran are:

```
docker build -t text_extract .
```

and then: `docker run -p 5000:5000 text_extract`

When I run the API and do a post request, I get the `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError` error.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: A lot of stuff is missing at the first glance: 1. does the base Docker image have AWS CLI installed? If not, can you install it using `apt`? 2. When AWS CLI is installed you could run the `aws configure`, but then you would need to respond to prompt. The best way to do this is probably by using the environment variables, `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

Comment: yes, AWS CLI is in the docker image. I understand that `aws configure` has to be done on prompt but I cannot figure out how to adjust my code for that. Can you suggest any edit on my code?

Comment: Like @MarkoE said, there are a lot of things missing to diagnose the problem. Where is the docker daemon running? If it is an EC2 instance, does the EC2 instance have an IAM role attached? If it does, does the IAM role have the relevant S3 permissions?